# AWS SQS "ECONNREFUSED" when sending message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Trying to send Message to AWS SQS from nodejs. I keep getting this specific error

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1161:14)
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: '',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2018-07-16T11:26:04.672Z }
```

I have set my credentials in my App, Given full access to my user for AWSSQSService. I can get all the details about the queue itself, queue names, etc. I just cannot send a message to the queue. My code below to send it

```
{

    let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: constants.AWS.AWS_REGION});
    let sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
    let SQSQueueUrl = ' https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*queueName*';
    let params = {
        MessageBody: 'demo', /* required */
        QueueUrl: SQSQueueUrl, /* required */
    };

    sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) 
            console.log(err);
        else 
            console.log(data);
    });

}
```

Comment: it seems like call from localhost to AWS is not allowed.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Anyplace where I can configure this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I came across the same error, remove the space at the start of your SQSQueueUrl, it solves the error.
so go with
**let SQSQueueUrl = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*queueName*';**

Answer (score -1):

That comes up when you don't configure access key and secret; you can specify it either on line 2 with the config or via environment

Comment: I have specified it in the environment. Like I said, I can get all the details of the existing queues, Queue Specific details, cannot write though

Comment: I assume the same exact snippet with sqs.getQueueAttributes() works? You have a space in your SQSQueueUrl

Comment: Ohh my bad. This actually solved it!!.Thanks. I was running sqs.listQueues() which doesn't require the SQS URL.

Comment: listQueues doesn't need a queueUrl. I guess they blanket redirect to localhost if validation doesn't pass

Comment: The problem was caused by the space in the URL. It has nothing to do with the access key or secret. These cause access violations, not connection refusals.